# Parsing a particular type of string in perl

Tags: regex, string, perl, parsing

I have the strings of the following type (where the quotes indicate that they are all on one line):

"AMINO-2,4,6-TRIIODOBENZOIC ACIDS              Hugo Holtermann, Baerum, Leif Gunnar Haugen, Oslo, and Knut      Wille, Baerum, Norway, assignors to Nye- 5"

"PROCESS     FOR      THE      PRODUCTION      OF       ETHYLENIC COMPOUNDS       Duncan Clark and Percy Hayden, Norton-on-Tees, Eng- 5 land,      assignors to ImperiaI Chemical Industries Limited, London,      England  "

I want to get everything after the title (the part that is all caps). So I would like to get:

"Hugo Holtermann, Baerum, Leif Gunnar Haugen, Oslo, and Knut      Wille, Baerum, Norway, assignors to Nye- 5"

"Duncan Clark and Percy Hayden, Norton-on-Tees, Eng- 5 land,      assignors to ImperiaI Chemical Industries Limited, London,      England  "

I have many more strings than these two but the basic formatting is that the title of the invention is always capitalized letters and numbers.

Is there a way to do this with regular expressions in perl?

Comment: It's *usually* capitalized, or always capitalized? Usually won't do you much good. I'm feeling that this might not be possible, depending on how well the names are formatted. If you had somebody's name that was just an initial i.e. 'J. Doe' I can't think of any logical way to separate that from the title.

Comment: it's always capitalized. I'm not looking for something that is 100% accurate. Something that's like 70-80% would be ok

Answer (score 1):

Well if it doesn't need to be 100% accurate, I would just look for the first capital followed by the first lowercase letter, and grab the rest of the line.

Something like this (my perl's a little rusty, forgive any syntax errors):

`$part_of_line = $full_line =~/([A-Z][a-z].*)/`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$text = "PROCESS FOR THE PRODUCTION OF ETHYLENIC COMPOUNDS Duncan Clark and Percy Hayden, Norton-on-Tees, Eng- 5 land, assignors to ImperiaI Chemical Industries Limited, London, England ";

if($text =~ m/(\b[A-Z0-9-, ]+)\b(.*)/) {
    print "$2";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried with this and got the output you were expecting

```
if($ip =~ m/([A-Z0-9,\- ]+)([A-Z]+[a-z]+.*)/)
{
      print "$2";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Titles always ends with capitalized letter+space, so this should work:

```
/^.+[A-Z]+ (.+)$/;
print $1;
```

Comment: This fails for both examples. It simply skips the first word in all caps.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.014;

my $re = qr
    /^                # Start of string
    [\p{Lu}\pN, -]+   # one or more uppercase letter or number or comma or space or dash
    (                 # start group 1
      \p{Lu}[\pL.']   # one uppercase letter followed by any letter or dot or apostroph
    )                 # end group
    /x;
while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    s/$re/$1/g;       # replace match by group 1
    say;
}


__DATA__
AMINO-2,4,6-TRIIODOBENZOIC ACIDS Hugo Holtermann, Baerum, Leif Gunnar Haugen, Oslo, and Knut Wille, Baerum, Norway, assignors to Nye- 5
PROCESS FOR THE PRODUCTION OF ETHYLENIC COMPOUNDS Duncan Clark and Percy Hayden, Norton-on-Tees, Eng- 5 land, assignors to ImperiaI Chemical Industries Limited, London, England
PROCESS FOR THE PRODUCTION OF ETHYLENIC COMPOUNDS D.Clark
PROCESS FOR THE PRODUCTION OF ETHYLENIC COMPOUNDS O'Connors
```

**output:**

```
Hugo Holtermann, Baerum, Leif Gunnar Haugen, Oslo, and Knut Wille, Baerum, Norway, assignors to Nye- 5
Duncan Clark and Percy Hayden, Norton-on-Tees, Eng- 5 land, assignors to ImperiaI Chemical Industries Limited, London, England
D.Clark
O'Connors
```